# GAE python self.redirect(http://google.com') to new browser window

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Is there a way to have a script run multiple

self.redirect to open links in different windows?

Well, self.redirect will only fire off once but I have multiple links that i want to programatically open in different browser windows.

How do i go about doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible using server side (python in your case) code. When you call self.redirect method it sends a 302 response code back to the browser, and the browser does the redirect.

To achieve opening multiple browser windows as you suggest, you will need to use javascript (but be aware of popup blockers!).

Here's an example:

```
urls = {'google': 'http://www.google.com',
        'yahoo': 'http://www.yahoo.com'}

s = ''.join(['window.open("%s", "%s");' % (url, name)
             for name, url in urls.items()])

self.response.out.write('<script>%s</script>' % s)
```